# catch post\get request in doPost\doGet (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

there is a server that return me sending confirmation of action to url that i give, but they can't know to tell me how the request look like so i build script that catch the request, and it's catch nuthing... i dont know what wron...

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl().toString());
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.postData.contents);
  Logger.log(e.parameters);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e).toString());
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl().toString());
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());
}
```

try to Set in the server some forms of the script's url with parameters and wuthout' and nothing its show that was requst But not beyond that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Apps Script, a script can be published as a web app if it meets these requirements

- It contains a **doGet(e)** or **doPost(e)** function.
- The function returns an HTML service **HtmlOutput** object or a Content service **TextOutput** object.

Please refer to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) here for more details

In your example, both functions don't respond to the incoming HTTP request. You are attempting to log something that doesn't exist in the execution context of your app.  You can inspect the output from **Logger** only when manually running GAS functions directly from the development environment (Apps Script IDE)

**doGet** and **doPost** are special functions in GAS that are not designed to be run like that. Instead, they receive an HTTP request from whatever app you are using to query them and return a response to the caller.

You must therefore explicitly return a response of the specified type (**HtmlOutput** or one of the MIME types associated with **ContentService**).

Here's a quick example of how you might handle errors in the doPost function

```
function doPost(e) {


try {

  let parsedRequest = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let response = {status: "ok", message: parsedRequest}

//catch Invalid JSON  error
} catch (error) {
    let response = {status: "error", message: error}
}

return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response))
                      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);                        
}
```

Depending on whether doPost throws an error or not, your calling app will receive a response that can be handled based on the outcome.

My understanding is that you are trying to use doGet / doPost as callback endpoints for some 3rd party app. In this case, you may find it more useful to append the incoming request to a Google Sheet to view its contents.

P.S. Switching from a default GCP (Google Cloud Platform) project to a dedicated one could also allow you to view the output from Logger but I'm not certain on that.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure that in other scripts I was able to log, are you sure it's impossible?

Comment: doGet work fine if i try sending something manualy, but the doPost not work even after i remove the 2 lines error

Comment: Sorry,  I have trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve. You previously mentioned that you are trying to handle a request from a remote server - is that correct? Also, what's a "2 lines error"? Please provide more context to your question.

Comment: 1. Does a remote server send a request to doPost? 2. If yes, do you expect to see the logs in the console of Apps Script Editor?

Comment: sorry about my english...

Comment: i trying to handle a request from a remote server. line 8 and 9 are Mistake. usually it's send post request, but sometimes get too. yes i expect to see the logs in the console or logger but i cant see..

Comment: can you write to me a form that send some parameters in post method? maybe i not write it right, i dont know...

Comment: ok i have to say that you are right, i can't log post request... I changed the code so that it would send it by email and indeed it was able to catch it and send it.
There is only one other problem, he changed all the Hebrew to rhombuses... why is he doing this? this what i change: 
  var log = JSON.stringify(e).toString();
  MailApp.sendEmail('mail-address','try',log);
  MailApp.sendEmail('mail-address','',JSON.stringify(e));

Comment: now i try another example (of post request) and it's good, the hebrew too' so i don't know...